# What (where) are elements that comprise WGS60 and FSHR1960?

Tags: coordinate-system, datum

Considering two 1960 geodetic ellipsoids (from [this list](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/datainterop/mergedProjects/FME_Workbench/predefined_ellipsoids.htm)), I've found the following parameters (from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160303184940/https://www.colorado.edu/geography/gcraft/notes/datum/elist.html)):

1. WGS60:   World Geodetic System of 1960: 6378165.0, 298.3
2. FSHR1960: Fischer – 1960 (Mercury): 6378166.0, 298.3

This is a new subject for me. With my current understanding, I believe that along with the two ellipsoid parameters, each of these should also include a list of locations or landmarks, and the coordinates of those locations in ellipsoidal coordinates. For each, the collection of the ellipsoid parameters together with the list of locations and their coordinates is called a datum.

If I am correct so far, are the lists available somewhere?

So far I have found many references to these, but not an actual complete listing of either datum.

Comment: @Zeus thank you for both discovering an obscure, four year old question with a broken link and an archived copy of the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at https://www.ngs.noaa.gov/PUBS_LIB/Geodesy4Layman/TR80003E.HTM WGS60 was a step on the way to WGS72.

The work was done by The US Department of Defense, so you may (or may not) get information on the use from there.

Comment: That's a helpful link to read, thanks! This is just post-Sputnik and in the early ICBM days, so I can imagine that some of it was hush hush. It seems it would be declassified now considering how much is public domain, but not necessarily so.